# SourceTree: how to do a git diff in the opposite direction?

Tags: git, git-diff, atlassian-sourcetree

How can I do a `git diff` in the opposite direction in the Atlassian SourceTree desktop app?  In other words, how do I get SourceTree to do `git diff b a` instead of `git diff a b`?

e.g., if my commits are in this order in my commits pane:

```
  3333
  2222
  1111
```

and I select 3333 and 1111, it will show me a diff of changes from 1111 to 3333 (i.e, `git diff 1111 3333`).

How do I make it do a `git diff` in the other direction, so that it's a diff of changes from 3333 to 1111 (i.e., `git diff 3333 1111`)?

(NOTE: this question is specifically about how to do this in the Atlassian SourceTree desktop app, **not** how to do it in git in general.)

[Here is a screenshot showing where I selected 2 commits in SourceTree to see the diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WGAQ.png)

Comment: For those who found this question from google search like me and are actually searching for the solution for `git` instead of SourceTree, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/53759965/3990767

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible in SourceTree.

I asked this question [here on answers.atlassian.com](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/194632/sourcetree-how-to-do-a-diff-in-the-opposite-direction) and found out from an Atlassian employee that the ability to do a diff in the opposite direction is not available, that a diff between commits is always shown in "forward history" order.

Some alternatives:

1. Use a different external GUI diff viewer

   -or-
2. Copy the files from older commit 1111 into the working tree for newer commit 3333, and then see the diffs in the working tree, e.g.,

> ```
> $ cd {repo}
> $ git diff --name-only 3333..1111 > /tmp/list_of_files_changed
> $ git checkout 1111
> $ mkdir /tmp/files_changed
> $ cp --parents -pr $(cat /tmp/list_of_files_changed) /tmp/files_changed 
> $ git checkout 3333
> $ cp -pr /tmp/files_changed/* .
> # (now look at the diff in SourceTree for the working copy)
> ```

Answer (score 15):

Supposing you need to diff a specific branch from your current branch, the only way is the [Berik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/439096/berik) answer because is not possible to inform branch as second argument.

So this show diff normal order:

> git diff branch_abc Makefile

and this show diff on reverse order:

> git diff -R branch_abc Makefile

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question.  The question isn't about how to accomplish this in `git`.  The question is about how to do this in the SourceTree app.

Comment: This answer doesn't address _the_ question but it does address _my_ question

Answer (score 0):

For me, what enabled me to reverse the diff direction, was to switch "Date Order" to "Ancestor Order". In my case, it would reverse the order in which the two commits in question were listed (in the most prominent panel in SourceTree, that lists all commits, thereby creating the graph) and this order seems to be what influences the direction when comparing two commits.

This probably won't be of help in every situation, but for me, it was.

Answer (score -1):

Can be one by switching the order of the commits:

```sh
$ git diff HEAD 21da2e
```

```java
-import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
-import java.net.MalformedURLException;
 import java.net.SocketException;
-import java.net.URL;
+import java.net.URI;
```

```
$ git diff 21da2e HEAD
```

```java
+import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
+import java.net.MalformedURLException;
 import java.net.SocketException;
-import java.net.URI;
+import java.net.URL;
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question.  The question isn't about how to accomplish this in `git`.  The question is about how to do this in the SourceTree app.

Answer (score -4):

It will work just fine to write

```
# will display the additions as + and subtractions as -
git diff first second

# will display the additions as - (in red) and subtractions as + (in green)
git diff second first
```

This should work just fine in standard git.

Comment: Sorry @I_am_John_Galt, I don't understand.  Write it where in SourceTree?

Comment: @RobBednark I'm not sure what sourcetree is. What your asking is a really basic operation in git with a normal command line tool. If sourcetree will not allow what I wrote then it sounds like a bug in sourcetree.

Comment: This is old but I believe you accidentally wrote the same command twice: The second one probably should be `git diff second first` (i.e. diff in the reverse order).

Comment: In case you want to use `git diff`, `git diff -R` will reverse the comparison.