# How to get opposite direction of `git diff origin/master`

Tags: git

If I run `git diff origin/master`, it shows me the changes in my local copy of the files in the repo against the files in the master branch in the remote repository.

I know you can list another parameter, and swap the parameters to get the opposite like this:

`git diff origin/branch_a origin/branch_b` becomes:
`git diff origin/branch_b origin/branch_a`

...but in my case, I want to compare with local (possibly uncommitted) changes.

Is there a way to do the opposite of `git diff origin/master`? So basically, the output would be the same, but instead of where it says lines were removed, it would say they were added, and vice-versa.

I know I could write a script to parse the text and reverse it, but I figured there must be a way to do it and I just don't know what it is / can't find the manual page on how to do it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Right: `git diff commit-specifier` compares the given commit's tree to the work-tree, with the commit's tree on the "left side" as `a/` and the work-tree on the "right side" as `b/`.  As you noted, it's tough to reverse these as the work-tree is implied by the lack of a second tree or commit specifier.

Fortunately, `git diff` has a `-R` option to reverse the two sides, so `git diff -R commit-specifier` does the trick.

Comment: `git diff -R` does the trick, thanks @torek!

Answer (score -1):

One option, perhaps not the most graceful, would be to just change the positions of the two branches involved in the diff.  So, you could try:

```
git checkout origin/master
git diff master
```

This assumes your current local branch is `master`.